How to convert date with UTC or EDT text in it, Flutter Date time
What is this Date time:
"2024-08-29 13:15:05 +0000 UTC" OR
"2024-08-29 01:33:40.774468453 -0400 EDT"
How I can convert & reformat it in flutter, what is the date format it will take ??
tried native flutter classes & intl library

You have to add the intl package to your pubspec.yaml:
You can use the DateTime.parse() method to convert the date strings into DateTime objects. However, since the second format includes fractional seconds and a timezone, you might want to use DateTime.parse() directly, as it supports ISO 8601 format well.
  String dateString1 = "2024-08-29 13:15:05 +0000 UTC";
  String dateString2 = "2024-08-29 01:33:40.774468453 -0400 EDT";

  // Parse the dates
  DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse(dateString1.split(' ').take(2).join(' '));
  DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse(dateString2.split(' ').take(2).join(' '));

  // Format the dates
  String formattedDate1 = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(date1);
  String formattedDate2 = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(date2);

  // Print the formatted dates
  print('Formatted Date 1: $formattedDate1');
  print('Formatted Date 2: $formattedDate2');


not working, not even parsing the date
